# HTML5 Audio "bug" (exacerbated on mobile)?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, mobile, windows-phone

I am not sure if this is a real "bug" or just an issue with my implementation of "multi-track" HTML5 audio.

https://github.com/kamranayub/wp81-ie11-audio-bug/tree/gh-pages

The test case can be run in Chrome, IE11, and FF.

http://kamranicus.com/wp81-ie11-audio-bug/

As it says in the readme, the issue is that IE11 (and 10?) for Windows Phone has delayed audio and regular audio "choppiness."

The delay is clear in the emulator log (and can be heard on a physical device):

[image: Emulator screenshot]

It's possible this is technically also an issue in desktop PCs, it's just too small to notice (due to better CPU power).

Any ideas for how to fix this? I did try a few things like pausing the audio initially or not calling load before play every time, but it didn't seem to work (in fact, calling `play` without `load` sometimes seemed to cause an exception).

#### Update (5/16/2014)

I think [this post](http://codetheory.in/html5-audio-behaviour-and-support-in-ios-and-android/) highlights the issues for iOS and Android, similar to what I'm seeing. The way the author "fixes" the delay is by storing the audio [in app cache](http://codetheory.in/fixing-html5-audio-problems-in-ios-and-android-mobile-browsers-to-overcome-the-limitations/).

With that in mind, I might be able to address the IE delay using app cache. On iOS/Android, we can probably also do the same to minimize delay. On other platforms, we already use Web Audio, so that's a non-issue.

Comment: Where is the question in your post?

Comment: This Stack Exchange site is for Windows Phone users, dev questions should go on Stack Overflow. Anyway, I'd try out the new dev preview update that came out today before investigating more, there were a few fixes to IE11 contained in that.

Comment: Today or yesterday? Also you're probably right, I assumed it was for dev+user questions related to WP.

Comment: @akid, has anyone else ran into audio issues on web pages in IE11 for WP8.1?

Comment: @akid, also I was hoping to turn this into a community wiki when it gets solved, so other devs can refer.

Comment: Cleared up the question now that I think I know what the issue is. May not be IE-specific at all.